# WinDBG customization: colors?

Tags: themes, windbg

Lately I've to do lots of work with WinDBG to eliminate some bugs. Seems to work... kind of. But is there any themeing function? I found some ways to change the font-color. But it doesn't seem to affect the background colors within the main screen.

If somebody knew a way, would be great. ;)

Comment: I added a bit of info to my original post that I think does now have the answer.  Sorry if this is too much info ... It isn't clear to me if the SO notification logic lets you know when an edit is made to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a directory named themes underneath the install directory.  It contains a file named themes.doc that discusses setting layout.

Ah - it is very simple.  I was fiddling with windbg and wondered about this some more.  It is under the view\options menu item.  Here is a really good [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/04/18/pimp-up-your-debugger-creating-a-custom-workspace-for-windbg-debugging.aspx) that talks about it.

Comment: That's just window-positioning stuff and unrelated with any color changes.

Comment: Okay.  I was relying on my clearly faulty memory. I had set up my own windbg environment at work and was thinking that I had seen some options besides positioning. I should have checked it before responding.